# What is the source of this image of the Batcomputer?

Tags: dc, comics, object-identification, batman

What is the source of this image of the Batcomputer, and who is the artist that designed it?

[image]

Note that it's not from *Justice League: Doom* as an earlier comment suggested.

Comment: It is possible that is a promotional art from the game Batman: Dark tomorrow from 2002. It was made by Kemco like the image suggest. In an old number of NintendoWorldReport they review the game and include an image of the batcave that looks very much like a zoomed out version of this image, 
Unfortunately i could not find out more. https://www.nintendoworldreport.com/media/691/4

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This looks like it could be from the video game: [Batman: Dark Tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Dark_Tomorrow) which was published by Kemco for the Nintendo GameCube and Microsoft Xbox.

I found [Nintendo World Report](https://www.nintendoworldreport.com/media/691/4) which links to a more zoomed out and smaller image of the Batcomputer and it seems to match.

There is also the site [Jeuxactu](https://www.jeuxactu.com/jeu/images-batman-dark-tomorrow-4279-6.htm) which has a much higher quality image that shows it is indeed the same Batcave and Batcomputer.

[image: Batcave and Batcomputer]

It's very likely that this is just concept art for the game. The game came out in 2003 and the graphics would not be able to match what we see in the image.

Comment: You can see the Kemco logo in the bottom left of the image you posted. I just googled "Kemco batman" and that was the first link to pop up. A reverse image search on TinEye gave me the link to Jeuxactu